# ruby condition returns nil instead of true/false

Tags: ruby, encoding, byte

I am using ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24) [x64-mingw32] and I came across something that previously worked in the 1.9.x version which does not work here. I was wondering if they changed the behavior, or if I am doing something wrong, or if this is a bug.

I am sending a byte down a socket `\xFF` and I receive it on the other end, but when I try to compare it to itself (which should return true) it does not return the expected output.

Example, I send the string `\xFF\x50\x00username\x00555\x00` and I receive it fine on the other end, but when i try to compare the first byte it to itself the conditional behaves wrongly.

Here is some code samples so you can see how I am handling the data (skimmed to relevant code)

```
class PacketReceiver
  def setpacket( buffer ); @buffer = buffer; end
  def getbyte
    byte = @buffer[0..0]
    @buffer = @buffer[1..-1]
    byte
  end
end

  def parsepacket(packet)
    #@receiver = PacketReceiver.new #defined elsewhere in code
    @receiver.setpacket packet

    return false unless @reciever.getbyte.eql? "\xFF" #the bugged line

    #Everything works beyond this point
    packet_id = @reciever.getbyte 

    case packet_id
      when "\x50"
        return sid_requesting_config
      when "\x51"
        sid_requesting_data_response
      when "\x52"
        sid_keep_alive_response
      else
        puts "failed"
        return false
    end
    return true
  end
```

In 1.9.X This `unless` statement was working fine. When debugging the data, the returned data from `@receiver.getbyte` is indeed "\xFF", but for some reason the `eql?` comparison is returning false instead of true causing the function to return false. If i remove this byte from the message and remove the check the rest of the code also calling the `getbyte` method works fine.

Also if I change the byte to "\x55" rather than "\xFF" the conditional `unless` statement works as it should.

I am not sure what is going on. Is \xFF reserved for something?

Comment: What encoding is `@buffer` in?

Comment: @muistooshort as you thought `@buffer` and `buffer` are both ASCII-8BIT encodings. How may I change this to UTF-8?

Comment: I undeleted my answer about the encoding problem. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that `buffer` is binary encoded (i.e. `buffer.encoding` is ASCII-8BIT). That means that this is happening:

```
c  = @receiver.getbyte # c also has binary encoding
ff = "\xff"            # ff is probably UTF-8
c.eql? ff              # comparing strings in different encodings gives you `false`
```

Instead, you should be doing simple numeric comparisons:

```
@receiver.getbyte.getbyte(0) == 255
```

Or even better, modify `getbyte` to return an integer.

I think your 1.9.X version was working mostly by accident, you should have been using a simple numeric comparison all along.

Keep in mind that you have bytes in your buffer (such as 0xFF and 0x00) that are not valid in UTF-8 strings so you should keep your buffer in binary. You can use `force_encoding` on slices of the buffer for the parts that are UTF-8 strings. You might want to look at [`String#unpack`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-unpack) as well.

---

Note that I'm linking to the Ruby 2.0.0 specific docs to match the Ruby version you're currently using.

Comment: Thank you this makes sense as I also thought this to be the problem. I guess I have to rethink how I can implement a binary byte packet protocol for my server. Edit: do note I was not referencing the getbyte function, but rather the PacketReceiver getbyte method (I forgot to include my declaration of @receiver). Although I still believe it is a encoding issue as you mentioned.

Comment: I'd think that the socket would be binary by default but I could be wrong. If it isn't then it should be pretty easy to make it that way. Then compare bytes as numbers and adjust the encoding when you slice out chunks of your buffers as strings.

Comment: So `@receiver.getbyte` is `PacketReceiver#getbyte` which returns a single character string? One moment while I fix things up.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, sorry for the mishap. I forgot to declare what @receiver actually was.

Comment: Check my update please. Interesting that I had *"Using simple numeric comparisons also neatly bypasses any strange and interesting encoding problems you might come across by accidentally comparing single character binary strings (your `@receiver` should be binary encoded BTW, it contains things that are invalid in UTF-8) and single character UTF-8 strings (such as `"\xFF"`)"* in my original answer.